# how to pass json data to controller in aspnetcore 2

Tags: json, controller

I have a json data.

Aim: I want to pass json data from view to aspnetcore controller, something like

```
public IActionResult(PRICES[] things)
{
}
```

but no success!..

model is:

```
public class PRICES :IEntity
{
    public int ID  { get; set; }
    public decimal? PRICE { get; set; }
    public decimal? PRICE2 { get; set; }
    public decimal? PRICE3 { get; set; }
    public decimal? PRICE4 { get; set; }
}
```

JSON data is:

```
"{"things":[{"ID":1,"PRICE":1.23,"PRICE2":2.34,"PRICE3":3.45,"PRICE4":5.67},{"ID":2,"PRICE":4.53,"PRICE2":6.34,"PRICE3":6.45,"PRICE4":7.67},{"ID":3,"PRICE":100,"PRICE2":0,"PRICE3":0,"PRICE4":0},{"ID":4,"PRICE":200,"PRICE2":3434,"PRICE3":0,"PRICE4":0},{"ID":5,"PRICE":11,"PRICE2":0,"PRICE3":2,"PRICE4":33},{"ID":6,"PRICE":3,"PRICE2":0,"PRICE3":0,"PRICE4":0},{"ID":7,"PRICE":4,"PRICE2":33,"PRICE3":0,"PRICE4":0},{"ID":8,"PRICE":1,"PRICE2":0,"PRICE3":0,"PRICE4":0},{"ID":9,"PRICE":100,"PRICE2":118,"PRICE3":3,"PRICE4":4}]}"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvT4Q.png)

it took 4-5 hours, no success. any response will be preciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action method accepts an array.`PRICES[] things`.But you are sending a Json Object.
Remove `things` part and send only `[{},{}]`. ie  send a json array.

or else refactor the action method to accept an object like

```
public class Things
    {
        public IList<PRICES> Things { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

Comment: it is interesting that, I done it mvc 5 with no problem , but in aspnetcore 2 Project ,I did same configuration, and it is not successful

Comment: SUCCESS!!! I had to add [FromBody] to aspnetcore controller so working part is:   public void GridinModeli([FromBody]IList<PRICES> things)
        {


        }